# Generating a polynomial which goes through $n$ points and is monotonically non-decreasing

Tags: polynomials, monotone-functions

Suppose we have $x_1<x_2<x_3<\cdots<x_n$ and $y_1<y_2<y_3<\cdots<y_n$. I was wondering if it would be possible to find a polynomial $P$ such that $P(x_i)=y_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ and $P$ is monotonically non-decreasing in the range $[x_1, x_n]$.

I know that there are infinitely many $P$ with degree $n$ satisfying the first condition, because finding the polynomial is equivalent to solving a system of $n$ linear equations with $n+1$ variables. This should mean there are also infinitely many $P'$, which might imply that there exists a $P$ where $P'\geq0$, but I'm not sure.

I know that, for $P$ to be non-monotonic, $P'$ must not contain a root with odd multiplicity. However, considering that there is no general formula for the roots of polynomials with degree at least $5$, it does not seem easy to check if there are roots within the interval.

That leads to two questions:

1. What is the smallest $d$ such that, for all $n$ and for all $x_1<x_2<x_3<\cdots<x_n$ and $y_1<y_2<y_3<\cdots<y_n$, there exists a $P$ with degree $n+d$?
2. Is there a general method to find a polynomial satisfying the two criteria?

Comment: How about $\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i) = 0$ and then $\dfrac{d}{dy}\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i) \geq 0$

Comment: Look at a simple case treated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1018423/305862). IMHO, the general case looks difficult. Turn to **spline interpolation** instead of polynomial interpolation for that. Polynomial interpolation is known for its oscillation trend (Runge phenomenon).

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm aware of the general numerical instability of polynomial interpolation. I wasn't thinking of necessarily applying this, but I was interested if this was in any way possible. Tom-Tom's line of thought in the provided link does seem promising, though.